# Common popup form, generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Web page generates a table that shows the results of a search. I want the user to be able to click on one of the results, have a pop up window which allows them to enter a message and have it stored on a database. Then the user clicks the send message button, the popup will then close and let the user continue the search results.

Here is the current code I have.

```
<h1>
    <center>
        <u>Casting Call Results</u>
    </center>
</h1>

<table border="1"; width="600px"; align="center">
<?php if(empty($results)) {echo "No Data returned";} ?>
    <?php foreach($results as $member):?>
    <?php $imgloc = "members/".$member['username']."/".$member['photolink'];?>
    <tr align="center">
        <td width="100px"> <img style="width:100px; height:125px" src="<?php echo $imgloc;?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $member['bio'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td><?php echo $member['username']?></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $member['email']?>"><?php echo $member['email']?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table></div>
<form action="castingcall.php">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Search Again"></center>
</form>
```

Here's the search return. I tried to insert the image but I don't have ten reputation points so here's a link to the search return so you can see what I'm talking about.

http://www.chicagofilmclub.org/screenshot.jpg

As you can see the table is generated by a for each so I am really confused as to how I can have each user an active link that calls the same page in a popup but can still $PASS the proper user name.

Answer (score 0):

Each person would have a link that would look something like this:

```
<a href="contactform.php?member=<?php echo $member['id']?>">Contact Member</a>
```

I am assuming you will give each memebr an ID in your database.

Then on the contactform.php page you would use something like this:

```
<?php 
  $memberId = $_GET['member'];
  //lookup memeber in database and do whatever it is you want to do with that info

?>
```

Comment: I tried this verbatim and it does not work.{yes, ID is already set up in my database.}I also tried about a dozen different iterations of this and each time I get a null return from the $_GET. I also tried $_POST to no avail. I also tried a constant instead data from $member and still I get nothing back.

Comment: When you say you get nothing back what do you mean?  Maybe you can post the contactform.php page you created. You should easily be able to get the member with the $_GET variable if you pass it in with the URL parameter member.